# Remove special characters in the string in java?

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

How to remove special characters in the string except "- _".
Now I use:

```
replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]", "")
```

it remove all special character  but i want to keep "- _" . Can anyone tell me how should I do?

Comment: What do you consider "special"?

Answer (score 12):

Use `replaceAll("[^\\w\\s\\-_]", "");`

What I did was add the underscore and hyphen to the regular expression. I added a `\\` before the hyphen because it also serves for specifying ranges: `a-z` means all letters between a and z. Escaping it with `\\` makes sure it is treated as an hyphen.

Comment: Can you place a `-` in the middle like that?

Comment: It might be caught as a range. Place a backslash ahead of it. I modified it.

Comment: I think the `-` has to be the last element of the set because if not it's recognized as a "range".

Comment: OP doesn't seem to have very thorough understanding of regexen. It would be better if you explained what you did and how it works.

Answer (score 5):

This might help:

`replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]", "");`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you need to *assign* the result (in case you're not doing that), because `replaceAll()` returns a *new* string, rather than updating the string (String is immutable):

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s-]", "");
```

Also note that the regex is quite simple:

No need to escape the dash `-` in the character class: When used as a *literal* in a character class, it must be either first or last (otherwise it indicates a *range*, like `a-z` etc).

No need to mention the underscore at all, because it is *already* listed: `\w` *includes* the underscore character!

Answer (score 1):

```
String str="owl@134_- abc";
String s=str.replaceAll(" [^a-zA-Z_-]+ ", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

It will replace the special character and white spaces from a given string.

Output will be: `owlabc_-`

Answer (score 0):

Use this `replaceAll("[\\w\\s\\-\\_\\<.*?>]", "")` ;

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]");
    Matcher match = pt.matcher(c);
    while (match.find()) {
        String s = match.group();
        c = c.replaceAll("\\" + s, "");
    }
```

Consider this

Answer (score 0):

*barely 6 years have passed and we have a lambda solution*

```
String str = "owl@134_- abc";
str.codePoints().mapToObj( Character::toChars ).filter(
    a -> (a.length == 1 && (Character.isLetterOrDigit( a[0] ) || a[0] == '-' || a[0] == '_')) )
  .collect( StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append ).toString(); // owl134_-abc
```