# Special Characters are not being removed

Tags: java, string, loops

So Im having an issue where my code will not remove special characters except spaces. I have tried subtracing indexes and even adding index and it still will not work. I have tried an input "BANANA & PEEL" and it wont work.

```
        String strMessage = input.nextLine();

        String strChars = " !@#$%^&&*() ";

        for(int i = 0; i < strMessage.length() - 1; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < strChars.length(); j++) {
                if(strChars.charAt(j) == strMessage.charAt(i)) {
                    strMessage = strMessage.substring(0, strMessage.indexOf(strMessage.charAt(i))) + strMessage.substring(strMessage.indexOf(strMessage.charAt(i+1)));
                    break;
                }
            }

        System.out.println(strMessage);
```

So my output should be BANANAPEEL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove special characters in the string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074485/remove-special-characters-in-the-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this way it will work quite well:

```
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String strMessage = input.nextLine();
            String strChars = " !@#$%^&&*()";
            String temp = "";
            boolean isInStrChars = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < strMessage.length(); i++){
                isInStrChars = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < strChars.length(); j++) {
                    if (strChars.charAt(j) == strMessage.charAt(i)) {
                        isInStrChars = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!isInStrChars){
                    temp+=strMessage.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(temp);
```

I just created a *'temp'-String*, and only if a character from the original String is NOT inside the *String strChars*, it will be added to the 'temp'-String.

EDIT: of course you can set the temp-String as the original strMessage at the end:

```
strMessage = temp;
```

Comment: Wow, I didn´t know this was possible. This answer was marked "the right answer" a few days ago and now it is not even helpful anymore? What happened lol?

Comment: oh sorry i didnt realize you can only have 1 right answer

Comment: Yes you can't have more than one accepted answer , hence I upvoted it as you accepted my answer :)

Comment: Thank you! You don´t have to make my answer the accepted one, I just thought it would be fair to make it at least "helpful". but thank you very much for your kindness! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use String Tokenizer class for separating your string.

```
StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(strMessage," !@#$%^&&*()");
while(t.hasMoreElements()){
System.out.print(t.nextToken()+""); }
```

suppose strMessage = "hello$#& w orl#d";

the output is helloworld

Answer (score 0):

Use StringTokenizer----

```
 StringTokenizer st1 =
             new StringTokenizer("hello$#& w orl#d", " !@#$%^&&*()");
        while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
            System.out.print(st1.nextToken());
```

Output - helloworld

Answer (score 0):

you could simply use String class' [replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Something like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "hel!lo$#& w orl#d";
    String replacementChar = " |!|@|#|\\$|%|^|&|(|)|\\*"; //Add you char separated by OR( |) 

    String s = source.replaceAll(replacementChar, "");

    System.out.println(s);

}
```

**output:**

helloworld

**Edit:**

As discussed in comments you don't want to use RegEx and only want to retain alphabets probably you can solve same using [Character.isAlphabetic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic(int))

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String strMessage = "BANANA & PEEL";

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < strMessage.length(); i++) {

            if (Character.isAlphabetic(strMessage.charAt(i))) {
                builder.append(strMessage.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        String finalString = builder.toString();

        System.out.println(finalString);

    }
```

Comment: Oh yeah forgot to mention I'm not actually allowed to use that stuff

Comment: Do you want to keep only alphabets

Comment: then you can do it old school way using Character class, I am editing my answer to help you

Answer (score 0):

*use a lambda function which removes all characters passed as string*

```
String strMessage = "BANANA & PEEL";
String strChars = " !@#$%^&&*()";

deleteChars.apply( strMessage, strChars );  // BANANAPEEL
```

[find deleteChars here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/remove-all-occurrences-of-char-from-string/56916146#56916146)